# Why cannot CSS transform-origin and transform be transited together?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/simonmysun/xowyzvus/15/

(code  will be appended)

In my browser the third transition is not smooth. It flash to the target in the very last time. It seems that it firstly ignored the transform-origin during the transition but applied it at the end. Why is this happening?

P.S. The brower may differ the result. Here on my Windows 10 device, Chrome 75 is flashing at the end of the transiton, in Firefox 70 it is trembling, while in Edge 41 nothing happens.

HTML:

```html
<h2>Transited: CSS transform</h2>
<div class="container"><div id="box1"></div></div>
<h2>Transited: CSS transform-origin</h2>
<div class="container"><div id="box2"></div></div>
<h2>Transited: CSS transform and transform-origin</h2>
<div class="container"><div id="box3"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#box1, #box2, #box3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: -8px -8px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5) 50%, rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5)), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5) 50%, rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5));
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1.5);
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
}
#box1 {
  transition: transform 1000ms, transform-origin 1000ms;
}
#box2 {
  transition: transform 1000ms, transform-origin 1000ms;
}
#box3 {
  transition: transform 1000ms, transform-origin 1000ms;
}
```

Javascript:

```js
var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
var box3 = document.getElementById('box3');
var transform = {
    x: 0,
  y: 0,
  scale: 1.5,
  ox: 0,
  oy: 0
};
box1.style.transformOrigin = `${transform.ox}px ${transform.oy}px`;
box1.style.transform = `translate(${transform.x}px, ${transform.y}px) scale(${transform.scale})`;
box2.style.transformOrigin = `${transform.ox}px ${transform.oy}px`;
box2.style.transform = `translate(${transform.x}px, ${transform.y}px) scale(${transform.scale})`;
box3.style.transformOrigin = `${transform.ox}px ${transform.oy}px`;
box3.style.transform = `translate(${transform.x}px, ${transform.y}px) scale(${transform.scale})`;
setInterval((function(){
    var step = 0;
    var steps = [{
    x: -100,
    y: -100,
    scale: 2,
    ox: -100,
    oy: -100,
  }, {
    x: -200,
    y: -100,
    scale: 2,
    ox: -200,
    oy: -100,
  }, {
    x: -200,
    y: -200,
    scale: 2,
    ox: -200,
    oy: -200,
  }, {
    x: -100,
    y: -200,
    scale: 2,
    ox: -100,
    oy: -200,
  }];
    return function() {
    transform = steps[step];
    step += 1;
    step %= 4;
    // box1.style.transformOrigin = `${transform.ox}px ${transform.oy}px`;
        box1.style.transform = `translate(${transform.x}px, ${transform.y}px) scale(${transform.scale})`;
    box2.style.transformOrigin = `${transform.ox}px ${transform.oy}px`;
        // box2.style.transform = `translate(${transform.x}px, ${transform.y}px) scale(${transform.scale})`;
    box3.style.transformOrigin = `${transform.ox}px ${transform.oy}px`;
        box3.style.transform = `translate(${transform.x}px, ${transform.y}px) scale(${transform.scale})`;
  }
})(), 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should never use `all` as `transition` property, because that loops through all animatable properties. Use `transform` instead.
2. If you truly want to animate things using javascript, you need something that updates every time the screen refreshes. `requestAnimationFrame` is what you need, because `setInterval` and `setTimeout` can activate during screen repaints which makes the animation "jumpy".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why shouldn't css transition also work?

Comment: `transition: all 1000ms` should be `transition: transform 1000ms`. :)

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that you want to do something dynamic, like the user clicking on a point in the #box and you animate to that point. Otherwise, use CSS's keyframe animation https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/ instead of all javascript code.

Comment: I understand and have noticed that `requestAnimationFrame` and CSS keyframe animation will work. However when `transition: all 1000ms` to `transition: transform 1000ms` doesn't fix it. Even `transition: transform 1000ms, transform-orgin 1000ms` does not help. Why is CSS keyframe animation working fine but transition is not? Thx

Comment: Because of what I wrote in point 2. Both can be responsible for lagging in animation.

Comment: Also, you never clear the interval, so it keeps on going. If you `console.log(step)` after the `step %= 4`, you will see that it restarts from 0.

Comment: Wait, so you want it to be a loop? Why don't you just remove the line `box.style.transformOrigin = `${transform.ox}px ${transform.oy}px`;` because that will make everything start to move around.

Comment: It is not lagging, If you change it to longer duration it become more obvious. It is only an example. I have updated the example link, If you have a look you will see the third transition is not behaving correctly. The brower may differ the result. Here on my device, Chrome 75 is flashing at the end of the transiton, in Firefox 70 it is trembling, while in Edge 41 nothing happens.

Comment: I wanted to set the `transform-orgin` so that I don't have to calculate the cordinates for scaling. I have used other approaches to finish this target but I am still curious why this is happening.